# Android studio эмулятор ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-emulator

в эмуляторе не дает вводить с физической клавиатуры на русском, на английском получается. Как исправить?

Comment: А можно чуть по-конкретнее? Код, логи итд?

Comment: @СергейПряничкин какой может быть код или логи, если я просто запускаю эмулятор выбираю любое поле ввода пытаюсь вводить с физической клавиатуры на русском языке и ничего не происходит, а на английском получается

Comment: @mario вводи с сенсорной

Comment: @RealKEK такое решение мне не подходит

Comment: В системе эмулятора настройте русский язык ввода.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja можно поподробней

Comment: Поменять насторйки на русский язык

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Собственно, в этой анимации все показано:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943492/russian-language-in-android-emulator?answertab=active#tab-top

Вкратце словами: заходите в настройки ввода, физические клавиатуры и добавляете русскую клавиатуру. При переключении в системе на нее, будет происходить ввод русских символов с клавиатуры компьютера. Чтобы вернуться назад на английский, нужно переключить в эмуляторе физическую клавиатуру на английскую.

Одна проблема остается, переключать эти клавиатуры с компьютера. По крайней мере у меня не получилось.

На компьютере языки переключать не надо!!!